# Turbo C Array Question

Tags: c, arrays, turbo-c

I just want to ask something about my code.

```
#define LIM 40

main()
{
       int day=0;
       float temp[LIM];

       clrscr();

       do
       {
               printf("Enter temperature for day %d.", day);
               scanf("%f", &temp[day]);
       }
       while(temp[day++] > 0)
}
```

I'm using TurboC, this code repeatedly asks the user to enter a temperature and stores the responses in the array ***temp***, until a temperature of 0 or less is entered. I've used a ***#define*** directive to give the identifier ***LIM*** the value of 40 because I want this program to accept any number of temperatures up to 40. **But It actually accepts up to 48**... What should I do so that it could accept up to 40 only?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the condition in while to the following: `while (temp[day++] > 0 && day < LIM)`.

Comment: I just have some query... I've set the temp into `temp[LIM]`=`temp[40]`. Isn't it enough to satisfy the condition?