# Turbo C Array Question

Tags: c, arrays, turbo-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turbo C Array Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080126/turbo-c-array-question)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIM 40

int main()
{
       int day=0;
       float temp[LIM];
       do
       {
               printf("Enter temperature for day %d.", day);
               scanf("%f", &temp[day]);
       }
       while(temp[day++] && day<LIM );
}
```

About the last line. Why is it not satisfied with `while(temp[day++] > 0)`? since I have set the **LIM** with the value of 40? Why should I add some additional condition, like **`day<LIM`**?

Comment: This program will accept any number of temperatures-- up to 40. But when I omit the line `&& day<LIM`, it accepts up to 48.

Comment: Please edit your old question with further information instead of starting a new one.

Comment: looking at the other question, you probably could have asked in the comments section of the accepted answer why it was a good idea to add the extra condition and then waited for the answerer to explain. But, it's sometimes a bit of "six of one, half a dozen of the other". The rul I follow is: if the second question can stand alone, independent of the first (and it's not an exact duplicate), it's probably okay. So (IMNSHO) both approaches would have been valid. Others may disagree of course, I'm just one cell in the swarm here.

Comment: because C isn't a [declarative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, if you enter 41 numbers, you will write to a location *outside* the array, invoking the dreaded undefined behaviour. When you attempt to write to `temp[40]` (the 41st element), you'll likely clobber memory that you shouldn't. It *may* work for a little bit beyond the end of the array but that's the nature of undefined behaviour. It's still not a good idea.

The `day < LIM` bit will force the loop to exit when you've entered 40 temperatures, regardless of what value you've actually entered.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid overflow of the array. The `temp` array has `LIM` cells, and you need to check that you don't try to access memory beyond that because it will cause an undefined behavior.

If you want to get more than 40 elements, you should allocate more memory for them, which can be done by defining `LIM` to a bigger value, like `#define LIM 48`.

Answer (score 1):

Because C doesn't do magic. It doesn't check if you step outside the allocated memory. It can't know if an access is valid or not so it tries it anyway.